# \usepackage[numbers,options]{natbib} \usepackage{bibentry}

Tags: natbib

I just started working with LaTex and I am trying to learn it by myself.
Still I have some problems.

When I use `\usepackage[numbers,options]{natbib`} and `\usepackage{bibentry}` I always get the error

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `options' for package `natbib'.
> ```

Comment: `options` isn't the name of an option for `natbib` that I know. Have you tried simply removing it?

Comment: @JosephWright 
Thank you very much, it worked. I thought that options is the name for natbib to use \citep{xx}. 

Nice that I feel supported in this stack exchange !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments